# How does Ubuntu's indexation work on a virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, indexing

I have read on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles the following sentence:

> Thankfully my computer indexes all my files every night while I sleep and I can search just the index, which will take only a few seconds, even on as an expansive a filesystem as mine.

And I was just wondering how does it work on a virtual machine? Does it occur even though the VM is powered off?

Comment: Just a guess: Most Linuxes know if they're in a VM or not, and disable auto indexing if so. Also, nothing happens to your computer or VM while powered off.

Comment: I think auto indexing is enable as you can use the locate command from the terminal (at least on Ubuntu using VirtualBox to virtualize it). I was thinking about something coming from VirtualBox to tell windows to sort of wake the VM up and tell it to index files on its virtual hard disk, but this is just my guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtual machine is just like an ordinary physical machine in most ways.  If it's not running, nothing is happening.

Therefore, if you power the virtual machine off (regardless of the state of the VirtualBox application or the host operating system), it will not perform *any* operation such as indexing files or doing anything else.

Comment: Then when does it happen?

Comment: @DRz When the virtual machine is up and running.

Comment: So the quote is wrong, even for a physical machine?

Comment: @DRz No, your computer may be running even if _you_ are asleep. The quote doesn't say anything about the computer sleeping.